# Conjugates in Field Theory

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, positive-characteristic

Let $K/F$ be an algebraic field extension.
We say that elements $\alpha$ , $\beta$ $\in$ K are conjugate over F if $\alpha$  and $\beta$ have the same minimal polynomial over F.

While reading *Field Theory* by *Pete L.Clark*, I came across that if $\alpha$ $\in$ $K$ \ $F$ then  the number of conjugates of $\alpha $ over $F$  is at least 2.

> **My attempt :** Suppose $F$ has characteristic $p>0$  .Suppose $\alpha$ $\in$ $K$ such that ${\alpha}^p = a$ for some a $\in F$ . Clearly minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ divides   f(t) = ${t}^p - a$ $\in F[t]$ . But f(t) = ${(t-{\alpha})}^p \in K[t].$  Hence clearly number of conjugates of $\alpha$  is $1$.

Can anyone explain me where I am going wrong?Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Isn't $\alpha$ supposed to be separable over $K$?

Comment: Nothing such is given in book.

Comment: You can take the number of conjugates, up to multiplicity, of the minimal polynomial. This fixes the definition.